# Bad request when trying to upload file in angular 2 using spring as backend

Tags: spring, angular

Hello i am trying to upload a file immediately when selected. i am getting a bad request 400. 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
My codes are below.

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" >




fileChange(event) {

    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        alert(ConnectionHelper.SERVER_URL
          +ConnectionHelper.MEDIACHANNEL+ConnectionHelper.UPLOADFILE)
        this._http.post(ConnectionHelper.SERVER_URL
          +ConnectionHelper.MEDIACHANNEL+ConnectionHelper.UPLOADFILE, formData,options)

            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/mediaChannel/logoUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String logoUpload(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file,HttpServletResponse res, MultipartHttpServletRequest req) {

            WebUtil wu = new WebUtil(res, req);
            wu.allowCrossSiteMessages();

            if (file.isEmpty()) {

            }

            try {
                // Get the file and save it somewhere
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Path path = Paths.get("images\\" + file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.write(path, bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "successfull";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cannot able upload file using http post,instead of you need use xhr  request

```
fileChange(event) {

    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData: any = new FormData();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));//If you need pass authentication token
            xhr.send(formData);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @rematnarab can you check file upload or not ,your error comes from this line JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) your backend response should json string

Comment: your return   return "successfull"; this should be json response not string

Comment: No, the request doesn`t even go to server.

Comment: can you add githup repo